# Debugging feature Using React in VS Code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

As mentioned in the document https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/reactjs-tutorial the development server should be running `npm start` but in my case we use `make run` which is configured in different way. So `make run` starts the website on port xxxx for us.

So how to setup other than `npm start` in VS Code.

Comment: You can find the scripts behind the npm start (and other) commands in your package.json file. I dont know what make run is, I thhink you will need to configure and add this yourself to the package.json file to make it work

Comment: @MajaOkholm there is lot of code written in Makefile which is quite difficult to trace it.. so that's the reason I wanted to know how to run `make run` through vs code editor